# Got error "xargs is not available" when trying to run a docker image

Tags: docker, gradle

I'm trying to run a hello word java application in docker. The application is produced by gradle init. I use gradle installDist to generate runnable file. I can run the runnable locally without any problem. But I got the error when I try to run from docker. Here is the docker file content:

```
FROM gradle:7.1.0-jdk11 AS builder
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle installDist

FROM openjdk:17-oracle
COPY --from=builder /home/gradle/src/build/install/app/ /app/
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["bin/app"]
```

The docker file is placed in the same folder with build.gradle and the docker build command is ran from that folder. Build runs successfully. But as long as I click run in the docker GUI, the container fails immediately with error message "xargs is not available"

Comment: FTR, note that the `openjdk` docker image is now deprecated. All other JVM docker images I tested do have `xargs` available. See the full list here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19682#issuecomment-1256202437

Comment: @Joffrey I have an image based on eclipse-temurin 11 here, which when I run it says xargs is _not_ available, but in the list at that link, it says it is. So there's that mismatch. I'm still trying to figure out why on earth docker needs xargs just to run a simple command.

Comment: It turns out some of the eclipse-temurin images are deliberately built with a very stripped down OS which not only lacks xargs, but also lacks yum, so the process to get additional packages installed becomes very unclear. Now that I have learned that such things exist, I just avoid those images. But it's still _very silly_ that docker images are published that can't even run a trivial Java app.

Comment: @Hakanai could you please give an example of an exact temurin image tag that has the problem? (with the full version/variant) If my post is incorrect on github I'd like to update it. I'll look for the exact tag I used to check xargs was present

Comment: @Joffrey "11-jre-ubi9-minimal" was the one we were using but it's possible every image with "ubi9-minimal" in the name will be the same. I believe we switched to just "11" and that one was OK.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the error describes, `xargs` is not available.

Looking at your Dockerfile, the jdk image you use, is based on Oracle Linux

So you need to add the following line, which installs the required package

```
RUN microdnf install findutils
```

For the Alpine based images the command would be:

```
RUN apk update && apk add findutils
```

Your Dockerfile should be

```
FROM gradle:7.1.0-jdk11 AS builder
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle installDist

FROM openjdk:17-oracle
RUN microdnf install findutils
COPY --from=builder /home/gradle/src/build/install/app/ /app/
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["bin/app"]
```

Comment: That makes a lot sense. I didn't notice I need extra dependency when I'm already using a jre.
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class gradle.App
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: gradle/App has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 62.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0
Can I ask one more? I'm getting this error. But I compiled with Java11 and run with Java17, I assume that will work. I'm really confused. Do you have some clue here?

Answer (score 6):

Since Gradle version 7.5, an explicit check for `xargs` presence has been added to solve [this issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19682), which is why you're seeing the message `xargs is not available` when running either the Gradle wrapper script itself, or a start script for an application that was built using the [Gradle Distribution Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html).

Note that it is quite rare that `xargs` is not present, because it's part of the POSIX standard. See this part of [xargs doc in POSIX.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) (emphasis mine):

> The xargs utility was usually found only in System V-based systems; BSD systems included an apply utility that provided functionality similar to xargs -n number. The SVID lists xargs as a software development extension. **This volume of POSIX.1-2017 does not share the view that it is used only for development, and therefore it is not optional.**

However `openjdk` Docker images version >= 14 don't include `xargs`. That said, those images are deprecated and should not be used anymore. I tested many alternative JDK images and compiled a list of the ones that do have `xargs` installed in [this comment on the issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19682#issuecomment-1256202437). At the time of writing, apart from the deprecated `openjdk` images, only `ubi9-minimal` variants of Eclipse Temurin images don't have `xargs`. All other images I tested are OK.

If you really want to use an image that doesn't have `xargs` by default, you may of course install `xargs` as part of the `findutils` package using the package manager of the image, as described in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73516388/1540818).