# xargs is not available with gradle v7.5.1 and docker-compose

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose, xargs

I am trying to upgrade gradle version from `7.4.2` to `7.5.1` but I'm getting a `xargs is not available` error message. I tried adding `RUN microdnf install findutils` in the `Dockerfile` as it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73516116/got-error-xargs-is-not-available-when-trying-to-run-a-docker-image) but is not working in my case, and I guess it is because I'm running the `gradlew installDist` command from outside, specifically I'm using docker-compose for local environment and integration tests, and travis.yml for CI. My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:17

COPY .dist/ /app/

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app/bin

CMD ["sh", "-c", "./app_name"]
```

and the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  app_name:
    hostname: app_name
    build:
      context: docker/app_name
    networks:
      - app_name
    volumes:
      - "./docker/app_name/.dist:/app-live:ro"
      - "./jacoco-bin:/jacoco:ro"
      - "./build/reports:/reports:rw"
    working_dir: "/app-live"
    command: "sh -c './bin/app_name'"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

and I use this command to build the application and run integration tests `./gradlew --info --profile build detekt koverXmlReport cucumber`, either from local or in the server, in the travis config, it fails in both

Comment: did you find the fix for this?